# Handling an association with an interface using ORM in Java

Tags: java, orm, associations

I want to whether it's possible to handle an **association** with an **abstract** Entity (i.e: an **Interface**), in another Entity. e.g:
I have a `class` called `Foo` which has an attribute `bar`, which is of type `Bar`, which is an `interface`. Multiple classes (`Bar1`, `Bar2`) realize `Bar` and are **all** also **persistable**.

```
class Foo{
  Bar bar; // this will be either Bar1 or Bar2
}

interface Bar{ 
  // some methods
}

class Bar1 implements Bar{
  String s; // Bar1 and Bar2 have different represantations ,hence they must be persisted to different tables
}

class Bar2 implements Bar{
  int i;
}
```

Now how can I handle this with an ORM in Java? i.e: so that when I retrieve a `Foo`, it's `bar` is an instance of one of the realizations of `Bar`.

Comment: Hibernate supports the three basic inheritance mapping strategies:

1. table per class hierarchy

2. table per subclass

3. table per concrete class

Comment: refer: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en-US/html/inheritance.html
I think you can handle interfaces in same way as Abstract classes in Hibernate.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can support polymorphic associations, but you'll need to make `Bar` an `abstract` base `@Entity` class instead of an `interface`, as JPA doesn't work well with interfaces, e.g.:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Bar {
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Bar1 extends Bar {
    private String s;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Bar2 extends Bar {
    private int i;
    ...
}
```

If you model it this way, you'll be able to query for `Bar` instances polymorphically using JP-QL, e.g. `select b from Bar`.

Reference:

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro002.htm#BNBQN

Comment: The question Specifically asks for an association with an **interface**. That is, to provide different "view"s to a single class, which cannot be accomplished using an abstract class.

Comment: The answer is correct. Probably it is dependent on the ORM provider. As long as I know for Hibernate it is correct. It does not play well with Interfaces. In order to work with interface you need to define implementation class. Once you do the the polymorphism is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

Related to ck1's answer, but with a single table.

Using `InheritanceType.JOINED` requires a table for the base class, and one table per subclass. If you use `InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE` with a `DiscriminatorColumn` you can store all of your entities in a single table and still retrieve in a single collection. You can also combine the `DiscriminatorColumn` with `InheritanceType.JOINED` if you want to be able to tell what type of object is in the base class, while keeping the subclass specific fields in separate tables.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "DISC")
public abstract class Bar {
    ...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("BAR1")
public class Bar1 extends Bar {
    ...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("BAR2")
public class Bar2 extends Bar {
    ...
}
```